# Can't find elements on second popup using Chrome

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup

I'm trying to find elements and click on them in my company's website. It happens while there is an opened popup, and a second popup is opened over the first one.
It works on Explorer browser, where I implemented a way to identify if there is a new window handle opens and switch to it, and when I'm done with the popup, I switch back to previous window.
However, recently we moved to Chrome, and my tests fail when there is a popup within popup.
I also noticed that on Chrome, I don't need to identify window handles, because when I open popup, I'm able to identify elements, and there is only the main window handle available.
But on this scenario, where I have a second popup on I can't reach the elements on it, nor frames.
What should I do? Tried everything possible.
Another thing - the popups can be dragged along the website, except for the first one, when there is a second one on.

Comment: You should include the markup (right-click on the popup, and choose, "Inspect", copy the markup shown there... it's probably a DIV) and the code you've tried.

Comment: It’s a kind of a windows form, there are many buttons and texts and even a table in the popup. None of them is found on Chrome. On Explorer it works. Even the iframe which wraps the whole popup is not found.